# How to specify a startup script in IronPython?

Tags: ironpython

The regular Python has PYTHONSTARTUP environment that lets you specify a startup script for interactive sessions. What is the equivalent in IronPython?

I searched the Web but couldn't find no IRONPYTHONSTARTUP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IRONPYTHONSTARTUP` variable indeed exists. [This work item](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/3361) says:

> Try `ipy.exe -h`. IronPython uses `IRONPYTHONSTARTUP` instead of
>   `PYTHONSTARTUP`. It is very conceivable that one may want to run
>   different startup scripts for CPython and IronPython. This difference
>   in environment variable name addresses the issue.

Comment: Ah cool. Thanks. It does work in the regular windows console. However, it doesn't seem to work in the Python Tools console inside Visual Studio. Is there a way to make the Python Tools load the startup script as well?

Comment: Good question. I suppose you restarted Visual Studio after setting the `IRONPYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable?

Comment: Yeah I did. It just isn't picking up the script.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation saying that the interactive window honors `IRONPYTHONSTARTUP`. Depending on the way that window embeds the interpreter, it's quite possible the variable is not supported...